# Trying to get the day from a str 10/08/2020

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get the day value from a str 10/08/2020.

I'm getting dates from a List containing a years worth of dates. I'm using the index num to do some date manipulation. First I need to get the day 08 from the date str.

Code segment:

```
 print("Today is = ",re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',calendarData[i]).strip())
 print("indexTarget is = ",indexTarget)
 dateTarget = re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',calendarData[indexTarget]).strip()
 print("Target date is = ",dateTarget)
 dayTarget = datetime.strptime(dateTarget,"%d")
 print("Day Target = ",dayTarget)
```

Console output:

```
Today is =  10/01/2020
indexTarget is =  281
Target date is =  10/08/2020
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\makeAReservation\makeAReservation\makeAReservation.py", line 183, 
in actual_time
    alarm(set_alarm_timer)
  File "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\makeAReservation\makeAReservation\makeAReservation.py", line 173, in alarm
    makeAReservation()
  File "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\makeAReservation\makeAReservation\makeAReservation.py", line 62, in makeAReservation
    getIndex4TagetDate()
  File "C:\Users\micha\source\repos\makeAReservation\makeAReservation\makeAReservation.py", line 46, in getIndex4TagetDate
    dayTarget = datetime.strptime(dateTarget,"%d")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: /08/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dateTarget` is a string, however `datetime.strprime` is for creating date object from string. Since you already have a string, you can just slice it and then print.

```py
print("Today is = ",re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',calendarData[i]).strip())
print("indexTarget is = ",indexTarget)
dateTarget = re.sub('[^!-~]+',' ',calendarData[indexTarget]).strip()
print("Target date is = ",dateTarget)

dayTarget = dateTarget[:2]

print("Day Target = ",dayTarget)
```

Comment: Thanks, I parsed the data as recommended and the striped off the unwanted control characters. Works fine now.

Comment: @PythonNewbe Hello. If the answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted.